# Why do I get the error of not finding the framework in Cordova when I compile?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova

Good Morning,

I have created a game with Gdevelop and when I export it to build it in iOS with Cordova, I get the following problem:

Commands:

cordova platform add ios

cordova build ios

```
juanjosegarciamanzano@macbook-pro-de-juan Jabato % cordova platform add ios 
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.stilugames.jabaliespacial
    Name: Jabali Espacial

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Debug]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `Jabali Espacial [Release]` target overrides the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Jabali Espacial/Pods-Jabali Espacial.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
Adding admob-plus-cordova to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-consent". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-consent" for ios

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUserMessagingPlatform":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (= 2.1.0, >= 1.1)

  In Podfile:
    GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (~> 2.0.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (~> 2.0.0), GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (= 2.1.0, >= 1.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have tried the solution that appears the most on the internet, but it doesn't work either, which is pod install --repo-update

Thank you for your help

What I would like is to be able to compile it correctly so that when I run Xcode I can upload it to the App Store. When I do it anyway with this error I get the following error when I make the archive:

[Module failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNQKd.png)